Unifying FOL atoms in C
I've written a small tool in C that computes the mgu of two atomic FOL formulas.
Any feedback is greatly appreciated, but something I would be very interested in is whether there's a better way of representing/traversing the AST of formulas/terms.
The compiler used is gcc 11.3.0 and the standard gnu11.
Thanks for all help :]
Makefile
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -std=gnu11 -Wall -fanalyzer

BIN := mgutron-3000

.DELTE_ON_ERROR:

$(BIN): main.c atom.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

atom.o: atom.c atom.h
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS)

.PHONY: test clean

test: atom.h atom.c
    @$(CC) -o $@ test.c $(CFLAGS)
    @echo "\e[1;33m"Running Tests:"\e[39;49m"
    @./$@
    @echo "\e[1;32m"All tests ran successfully!"\e[39;49m"
    @rm -rf $@

clean:
    rm -rf *.o $(BIN)

main.c
/*
 * ABOUT: Simple program that computes the mgu of atomic FOL formulas.
 *
 *        For a simple explanation of unification see: 
 *        https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse415/00sp/lecture-slides/Unification/tsld001.htm
 */
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include "atom.h"

void print_help(const char *path);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Parse command line args
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        print_help(argv[0]);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    atom *a1 = parse_atom(argv[1]);
    atom *a2 = parse_atom(argv[2]);

    if (a1 == NULL || a2 == NULL)
    {
        puts("invalid atom(s)!");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Unify atoms & print result
    size_t n;
    subst *mgu = NULL;
    if (!get_mgu(a1, a2, &mgu, &n))
    {
        puts("formulas aren't unifiable!");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    print_unifier(mgu, n, stdout);
    puts("");

    free_unifier(mgu, n);
    free_atom(a1);
    free_atom(a2);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void print_help(const char *path)
{
    const char msg[] =
        "Usage: %s ATOM ATOM\n"
        "Computes the mgu (most general unifier) of two atomic FOL formulas.\n"
        "\n"
        "Atomic formulas are generated by the following grammar:\n"
        "\tATOM       ::=  PREDICATE [TERM-LIST]\n"
        "\tPREDICATE  ::=  'P' | 'Q' | 'R'\n"
        "\tTERM-LIST  ::=  '(' TERM {',' TERM} ')'\n"
        "\tTERM       ::=  FUNCTION TERM-LIST | VARIABLE\n"
        "\tFUNCTION   ::=  'f' | 'g' | 'h'\n"
        "\tVARIABLE   ::=  'x' | 'y' | 'z' | 'u' | 'v'\n"
        "\tCONSTANT   ::=  'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'k' | 'l'\n"
        "\n"
        "Examples:\n"
        "\tP, Q(z,a), R(f(x,c),h(g(x),y))\n";
    printf(msg, path);
}

atom.h
#ifndef ATOM_H
#define ATOM_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#ifdef __GNUC__
    #define GNU(S) S
#else
    #define GNU(S)
#endif

/* A term is either
 * - a variable x,
 * - a constant c, or
 * - a function application f(t1, ..., tn) of f to terms t1, ..., tn.
 */
typedef struct term term;

/* An atomic formula is either
 * - a predicate symbol P, or
 * - a predicate symbol P(t1, ..., tn) with terms t1, ..., tn.
 */
typedef struct atom atom;

GNU(__attribute__((nonnull)))
void free_atom(atom *a);

GNU(__attribute__((nonnull)))
atom *parse_atom(const char *s);

GNU(__attribute__((nonnull(1), nonnull(2))))
void print_atom(const atom *a, FILE *ofile);

/* An elementary substitution t/var. */
typedef struct
{
    term *t;
    char var;
} subst;

GNU(__attribute__((nonnull)))
void free_unifier(subst *u, size_t n);

/* Computes the most-general unifier of a1 & a2.
 * Returns true if a1, a2 are unifiable, the unifier is placed in mgu and the number
 * of elementary substitutions is placed in n.
 * Returns false otherwise.
 */
GNU(__attribute__((nonnull(1), nonnull(2), nonnull(3), nonnull(4))))
bool get_mgu(const atom *a1, const atom *a2, subst **mgu, size_t *n);

GNU(__attribute__((nonnull(1), nonnull(3))))
void print_unifier(const subst *mgu, size_t n, FILE *outfile);

#endif

atom.c
#include "atom.h"

#include <string.h>
#include <sys/cdefs.h>

GNU(__attribute__((returns_nonnull, malloc, alloc_size(1))))
static void *safe_malloc(size_t n)
{
    void *memory = malloc(n);
    if (memory == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failure: malloc(%zu)!\n", n);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return memory;
}

GNU(__attribute__((returns_nonnull, alloc_size(2))))
static void *safe_realloc(void *mem, size_t n)
{
    void *memory = realloc(mem, n);
    if (memory == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failure: realloc(..., %zu)!\n", n);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return memory;
}

typedef enum
{
    APPLICATION,
    VARIABLE,
    CONSTANT,
} term_type;

typedef struct term
{
    term_type type;
    union
    {
        char var;
        char con;
        struct
        {
            char fname;
            size_t argc;
            struct term **args;
        } app;
    } val;
} term;

GNU(__attribute__((returns_nonnull, malloc)))
static term *new_variable(char varname)
{
    term *t = safe_malloc(sizeof(term));
    *t = (term) {
        .type = VARIABLE,
        .val.var = varname,
    };

    return t;
}

GNU(__attribute__((returns_nonnull, malloc)))
static term *new_constant(char constant)
{
    term *t = safe_malloc(sizeof(term));
    *t = (term) {
        .type = CONSTANT,
        .val.con = constant,
    };

    return t;
}

GNU(__attribute__((returns_nonnull, malloc)))
static term *new_application(char fname, size_t argc, struct term *args[static 1])
{
    term *t = safe_malloc(sizeof(term));
    *t = (term) {
        .type = APPLICATION,
        .val.app = {
            .fname = fname,
            .argc = argc,
            .args = args,
        },
    };

    return t;
}

GNU(__attribute__((nonnull)))
void free_term(term *t)
{
    if (APPLICATION == t->type)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < t->val.app.argc; ++i)
        {
            free_term(t->val.app.args[i]);
        }
        free(t->val.app.args);
    }
    free(t);
}

GNU(__attribute__((nonnull(1), nonnull(2))))
void print_term(const term *t, FILE *ofile)
{
    switch (t->type)
    {
    case VARIABLE:
        fputc(t->val.var, ofile);
        break;

    case CONSTANT:
        fputc(t->val.con, ofile);
        break;

    case APPLICATION:
        fputc(t->val.app.fname, ofile);
        fputc('(', ofile);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < t->val.app.argc; ++i)
        {
            print_term(t->val.app.args[i], ofile);
            fputc(',', ofile);
        }
        fputc('\b', ofile);
        fputc(')', ofile);
        break;
    }
}

GNU(__attribute__((nonnull)))
static void free_arg_list(term **args, size_t argc)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        free_term(args[i]);
    }
    free(args);
}

static term *parse_term(const char **s);

GNU(__attribute__((nonnull)))
static term **parse_arg_list(const char **s, size_t *n)
{
    const char *str = *s;

    if (*str != '(')
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    size_t cap = 1;
    size_t argc = 0;
    term **args = safe_malloc(cap*sizeof(term*));

    do
    {
        ++str;

        if (argc >= cap)
        {
            cap *= 2;

            // I would prefer:
            //   args = safe_realloc(args, cap*sizeof(term*));
            // but -fanalyzer seems to find a leak in my test file when using realloc
            // that I just can't figure out... :(
            term **args2 = safe_malloc(cap*sizeof(term*));
            for (size_t i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
            {
                args2[i] = args[i];
            }
            free(args);
            args = args2;
        }

        args[argc] = parse_term(&str);
        if (args[argc] == NULL)
        {
            free_arg_list(args, argc);
            return NULL;
        }

        ++argc;
    } while (*str == ',');

    if (*str != ')')
    {
        free_arg_list(args, argc);
        return NULL;
    }
    ++str;

    *s = str;
    *n = argc;
    return args;
}

GNU(__attribute__((nonnull)))
static term *parse_term(const char **s)
{
    const char *str = *s;
    if (strchr("fgh", *str) != NULL)
    {
        // Parse function application
        char fname = *str;
        ++str;

        size_t argc;
        term **args = parse_arg_list(&str, &argc);
        if (args == NULL)
        {
            return NULL;
        }

        *s = str;
        return new_application(fname, argc, args);
    }
    else if (strchr("xyzuv", *str) != NULL)
    {
        // Parse variable
        char variable = *str;
        ++str;

        *s = str;
        return new_variable(variable);
    }
    else if (strchr("abckl", *str) != NULL)
    {
        // Parse constant
        char constant = *str;
        ++str;

        *s = str;
        return new_constant(constant);
    }

    return NULL;
}

struct atom
{
    char predicate;
    size_t argc;
    struct term **args;
};

void free_atom(atom *a)
{
    free_arg_list(a->args, a->argc);
    free(a);
}

void print_atom(const atom *a, FILE *ofile)
{
    fputc(a->predicate, ofile);
    if (a->argc != 0)
    {
        fputc('(', ofile);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < a->argc; ++i)
        {
            print_term(a->args[i], ofile);
            fputc(',', ofile);
        }
        fputc('\b', ofile);
        fputc(')', ofile);
    }
}

atom *parse_atom(const char *s)
{
    if (strchr("PQR", *s) == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    char predicate = *s;
    ++s;

    size_t argc = 0;
    term **args = NULL;
    if (*s != '\0')
    {
        args = parse_arg_list(&s, &argc);
        if (args == NULL)
        {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    if (*s != '\0')
    {
        free_arg_list(args, argc);
        return NULL;
    }

    atom *a = safe_malloc(sizeof(atom));
    *a = (atom) {
        .predicate = predicate,
        .argc = argc,
        .args = args,
    };

    return a;
}

void free_unifier(subst *u, size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        subst s = u[i];
        free_term(s.t);
    }
    free(u);
}

/* ==UNIFICATION==
 * The algorithm implemented roughly mirrors the one described in
 * [1] https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse415/00sp/lecture-slides/Unification/tsld009.htm
 */

GNU(__attribute__((nonnull)))
static bool occurs_in(char var, const term *t)
{
    switch (t->type)
    {
    case VARIABLE:
        return var == t->val.var;
        break;
    case CONSTANT:
        return false;
        break;
    case APPLICATION:
        for (size_t i = 0; i < t->val.app.argc; ++i)
        {
            if (occurs_in(var, t->val.app.args[i]))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    return false;
}

GNU(__attribute__((nonnull(1), nonnull(2))))
static bool equal_term(const term *t1, const term *t2)
{
    if (t1->type != APPLICATION)
    {
        return memcmp(t1, t2, sizeof(*t1)) == 0;
    }

    if (t2->type != APPLICATION || t1->val.app.fname != t2->val.app.fname || t1->val.app.argc != t2->val.app.argc)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < t1->val.app.argc; ++i)
    {
        if (!equal_term(t1->val.app.args[i], t2->val.app.args[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

GNU(__attribute__((returns_nonnull, nonnull)))
static term *copy_term(const term *t)
{
    term *t2 = safe_malloc(sizeof(term));
    *t2 = *t;

    if (t->type == APPLICATION)
    {
        size_t argc = t->val.app.argc;
        term **args = safe_malloc(argc*sizeof(term*));

        for (size_t i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        {
            term *arg = copy_term(t->val.app.args[i]);
            args[i] = arg;
        }
        t2->val.app.args = args;
    }

    return t2;
}

GNU(__attribute__((returns_nonnull, nonnull(1), nonnull(2))))
static term *apply_subst(term *in, const term *t, char var)
{
    if (in->type == VARIABLE && in->val.var == var)
    {
        free_term(in);
        return copy_term(t);
    }

    if (in->type == APPLICATION)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < in->val.app.argc; ++i)
        {
            in->val.app.args[i] = apply_subst(in->val.app.args[i], t, var);
        }
    }

    return in;
}

GNU(__attribute__((nonnull(1), nonnull(3), nonnull(4), nonnull(5))))
static bool add_subst(const term *t, char var, subst **mgu, size_t *n, size_t *cap)
{
    // Occur check
    if (occurs_in(var, t))
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < *n; ++i)
    {
        // Don't substitute the same variable twice
        subst s = (*mgu)[i];
        if (s.var == var)
        {
            return equal_term(s.t, t);
        }
        
        // Occur check
        apply_subst(s.t, t, var);
        if (occurs_in(s.var, s.t))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Resize array & add new substitution
    subst s = (subst) { copy_term(t), var };
    if (*n == 0)
    {
        *cap += 1;
        *mgu = safe_malloc(*cap*sizeof(s));
    }
    else if (*n >= *cap)
    {
        *cap *= 2;      
        *mgu = safe_realloc(*mgu, *cap*sizeof(s));
    }

    (*mgu)[*n] = s;
    *n += 1;

    return true;
}

/* Roughly implements [1]s step 4a.-4d. */
GNU(__attribute__((nonnull(1), nonnull(2), nonnull(3), nonnull(4), nonnull(5))))
static bool subst_terms(const term *t1, const term *t2, subst **mgu, size_t *n, size_t *cap)
{
    if (t1->type == VARIABLE)
    {
        if (t2->type == VARIABLE && t1->val.var == t2->val.var)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (add_subst(t2, t1->val.var, mgu, n, cap))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (t2->type == VARIABLE)
    {
        return subst_terms(t2, t1, mgu, n, cap);
    }

    if (t1->type == APPLICATION && t2->type == APPLICATION
        && t1->val.app.fname == t2->val.app.fname
        && t1->val.app.argc == t2->val.app.argc)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < t1->val.app.argc; ++i)
        {
            term *e1 = t1->val.app.args[i];
            term *e2 = t2->val.app.args[i];
            if (!subst_terms(e1, e2, mgu, n, cap))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    if (t1->type == CONSTANT && t2->type == CONSTANT && t1->val.con == t2->val.con)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool get_mgu(const atom *a1, const atom *a2, subst **mgu, size_t *n)
{ 
    *mgu = NULL;
    *n = 0;
    if (a1->predicate != a2->predicate)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (a1->argc != a2->argc)
    {
        return false;
    }

    size_t cap = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a1->argc; ++i)
    {
        if (!subst_terms(a1->args[i], a2->args[i], mgu, n, &cap))
        {
            free_unifier(*mgu, *n);
            *mgu = NULL;
            *n = 0;
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

void print_unifier(const subst *mgu, size_t n, FILE *outfile)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        fputs("{}", outfile);
        return;
    }

    putc('{', outfile);
    print_term(mgu[0].t, outfile);
    fprintf(outfile, "/%c",  mgu[0].var);
    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        fputs(", ", outfile);
        print_term(mgu[i].t, outfile);
        fprintf(outfile, "/%c",  mgu[i].var);
    }
    putc('}', outfile);
}

test.c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "atom.c"

subst new_subst(const char *s, char var)
{
    term *t = parse_term(&s);
    return (subst) { t, var };
}

int testc = 0;

void assert_mgu(const atom *a1, const atom *a2, int m, ...)
{
    va_list expect;
    va_start(expect, m);

    subst *mgu;
    size_t n;

    // Are they unifiable?
    assert(get_mgu(a1, a2, &mgu, &n));

    // Are the elemental substitutions right?
    assert(n == m);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        subst s = va_arg(expect, subst);
        assert(s.var == mgu[i].var);
        assert(equal_term(s.t, mgu[i].t));
    }

    free_unifier(mgu, n);
    va_end(expect);

    printf("Test %d ran successfully!\n", testc++);
}

void assert_not_unifiable(const atom *a1, const atom *a2)
{
    subst *mgu = NULL;
    size_t n = 0;

    assert(!get_mgu(a1, a2, &mgu, &n));
    assert(n == 0);
    assert(mgu == NULL);

    printf("Test %d ran successfully!\n", testc++);
}

int main(void)
{
    atom *a1, *a2;
    subst s1, s2;

    // Test unifiable atoms

    // Example from
    // https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse415/00sp/lecture-slides/Unification/tsld012.htm
    a1 = parse_atom("P(a,f(x,a))");
    a2 = parse_atom("P(a,f(g(y),y))");
    s1 = new_subst("g(a)", 'x');
    s2 = new_subst("a", 'y');
    assert_mgu(a1, a2, 2, s1, s2);
    assert_mgu(a1, a1, 0);
    assert_mgu(a2, a2, 0);
    free_atom(a1);
    free_atom(a2);
    free_term(s1.t);
    free_term(s2.t);

    // mgu(P, P) = {}
    a1 = parse_atom("P");
    a2 = parse_atom("P");
    assert_mgu(a1, a2, 0);
    free_atom(a1);
    free_atom(a2);

    // mgu(P(x), P(y)) = { y/x }
    // mgu(P(y), P(x)) = { x/y }
    a1 = parse_atom("P(x)");
    a2 = parse_atom("P(y)");
    s1 = new_subst("y", 'x');
    s2 = new_subst("x", 'y');
    assert_mgu(a1, a2, 1, s1);
    assert_mgu(a2, a1, 1, s2);
    assert_mgu(a1, a1, 0);
    assert_mgu(a2, a2, 0);
    free_atom(a1);
    free_atom(a2);
    free_term(s1.t);
    free_term(s2.t);

    // mgu(R(x,l), R(g(y),y)) = { g(l)/y, l/y }
    a1 = parse_atom("R(x,l)");
    a2 = parse_atom("R(g(y),y)");
    s1 = new_subst("g(l)", 'x');
    s2 = new_subst("l", 'y');
    assert_mgu(a1, a2, 2, s1, s2);
    assert_mgu(a1, a1, 0);
    assert_mgu(a2, a2, 0);
    free_atom(a1);
    free_atom(a2);
    free_term(s1.t);
    free_term(s2.t);

    // mgu(Q(x,h(u)), Q(h(u),x)) = { g(u)/x }
    a1 = parse_atom("Q(x,h(u))");
    a2 = parse_atom("Q(h(u),x)");
    s1 = new_subst("h(u)", 'x');
    assert_mgu(a1, a2, 1, s1);
    assert_mgu(a1, a1, 0);
    assert_mgu(a2, a2, 0);
    free_atom(a1);
    free_atom(a2);
    free_term(s1.t);

    // mgu(R(f(h(x),h(g(y)))), R(f(h(f(u,z)),h(z)))) = { f(u,g(y))/x, g(y)/z }
    a1 = parse_atom("R(f(h(x),h(g(y))))");
    a2 = parse_atom("R(f(h(f(u,z)),h(z)))");
    s1 = new_subst("f(u,g(y))", 'x');
    s2 = new_subst("g(y)", 'z');
    assert_mgu(a1, a2, 2, s1, s2);
    assert_mgu(a1, a1, 0);
    assert_mgu(a2, a2, 0);
    free_atom(a1);
    free_atom(a2);
    free_term(s1.t);
    free_term(s2.t);

    // Test non-unifiable atoms

    // mgu(P, Q) = mgu(Q, P) = undefined
    a1 = parse_atom("P");
    a2 = parse_atom("Q");
    assert_not_unifiable(a1, a2);
    assert_not_unifiable(a2, a1);
    free_atom(a1);
    free_atom(a2);

    // mgu(R(h(b)), Q) = mgu(Q, R(h(b))) = undefined
    a1 = parse_atom("P");
    a2 = parse_atom("Q");
    assert_not_unifiable(a1, a2);
    assert_not_unifiable(a2, a1);
    free_atom(a1);
    free_atom(a2);

    // mgu(P(v,f(k)), Q(v,f(k))) = mgu(Q(v,f(k)), P(v,f(k))) = undefined
    a1 = parse_atom("P(v,f(k))");
    a2 = parse_atom("Q(v,f(k))");
    assert_not_unifiable(a1, a2);
    assert_not_unifiable(a2, a1);
    free_atom(a1);
    free_atom(a2);

    // mgu(Q(f(g(c)),c), Q(f(x),h(y))) = mgu(Q(f(x),h(y)), Q(f(g(c)),c)) = undefined
    a1 = parse_atom("Q(f(g(c)),c)");
    a2 = parse_atom("Q(f(x),h(y))");
    assert_not_unifiable(a1, a2);
    assert_not_unifiable(a2, a1);
    free_atom(a1);
    free_atom(a2);

    // mgu(R(x,g(u)), R(k,x)) = mgu(R(k,x), R(x,g(u))) = undefined
    a1 = parse_atom("R(x,g(u))");
    a2 = parse_atom("R(k,x)");
    assert_not_unifiable(a1, a2);
    assert_not_unifiable(a2, a1);
    free_atom(a1);
    free_atom(a2);

    // mgu(P(x,f(x)), P(h(y),y)) = mgu(P(h(y),y), P(x,f(x))) = undefined
    a1 = parse_atom("P(x,f(x))");
    a2 = parse_atom("P(h(y),y)");
    assert_not_unifiable(a1, a2);
    assert_not_unifiable(a2, a1);
    free_atom(a1);
    free_atom(a2);

    // mgu(R(f(a,x)), R(f(u))) = mgu(R(f(a,x)), R(f(u))) = undefined
    a1 = parse_atom("R(f(a,x))");
    a2 = parse_atom("R(f(u))");
    assert_not_unifiable(a1, a2);
    assert_not_unifiable(a2, a1);
    free_atom(a1);
    free_atom(a2);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;    
}

link to the repo

Error messages go to standard error:
if (a1 == NULL || a2 == NULL)
{
    puts("invalid atom(s)!");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

Use fputs("invalid atom(s)!", stderr); instead. I also do not see the point of taking another atom as input when the first one failed.
atom.c is quite inflexible:
All the safe_malloc()/safe_realloc() render the code unusable as a library outside of this application. That wouldn't be the case if you return a result instead of printing unsolicited error messages to stderr and exiting.
Reduce duplication in tests:
// Test non-unifiable atoms

    // mgu(P, Q) = mgu(Q, P) = undefined
    a1 = parse_atom("P");
    a2 = parse_atom("Q");
    assert_not_unifiable(a1, a2);
    assert_not_unifiable(a2, a1);
    free_atom(a1);
    free_atom(a2);

    // mgu(R(h(b)), Q) = mgu(Q, R(h(b))) = undefined
    a1 = parse_atom("P");
    a2 = parse_atom("Q");
    assert_not_unifiable(a1, a2);
    assert_not_unifiable(a2, a1);
    free_atom(a1);
    free_atom(a2);

    // mgu(P(v,f(k)), Q(v,f(k))) = mgu(Q(v,f(k)), P(v,f(k))) = undefined
    a1 = parse_atom("P(v,f(k))");
    a2 = parse_atom("Q(v,f(k))");
    assert_not_unifiable(a1, a2);
    assert_not_unifiable(a2, a1);
    free_atom(a1);
    free_atom(a2);

    // mgu(Q(f(g(c)),c), Q(f(x),h(y))) = mgu(Q(f(x),h(y)), Q(f(g(c)),c)) = undefined
    a1 = parse_atom("Q(f(g(c)),c)");
    a2 = parse_atom("Q(f(x),h(y))");
    assert_not_unifiable(a1, a2);
    assert_not_unifiable(a2, a1);
    free_atom(a1);
    free_atom(a2);

    // mgu(R(x,g(u)), R(k,x)) = mgu(R(k,x), R(x,g(u))) = undefined
    a1 = parse_atom("R(x,g(u))");
    a2 = parse_atom("R(k,x)");
    assert_not_unifiable(a1, a2);
    assert_not_unifiable(a2, a1);
    free_atom(a1);
    free_atom(a2);

    // mgu(P(x,f(x)), P(h(y),y)) = mgu(P(h(y),y), P(x,f(x))) = undefined
    a1 = parse_atom("P(x,f(x))");
    a2 = parse_atom("P(h(y),y)");
    assert_not_unifiable(a1, a2);
    assert_not_unifiable(a2, a1);
    free_atom(a1);
    free_atom(a2);

    // mgu(R(f(a,x)), R(f(u))) = mgu(R(f(a,x)), R(f(u))) = undefined
    a1 = parse_atom("R(f(a,x))");
    a2 = parse_atom("R(f(u))");
    assert_not_unifiable(a1, a2);
    assert_not_unifiable(a2, a1);
    free_atom(a1);
    free_atom(a2);

The only difference in all these code blocks are the string literals passed to parse_atom(). Consider writing a wrapper for the code block and then doing:
    // mgu(P, Q) = mgu(Q, P) = undefined
    foo("P", "Q");

    // mgu(R(h(b)), Q) = mgu(Q, R(h(b))) = undefined
    foo("P", "Q");

    // mgu(P(v,f(k)), Q(v,f(k))) = mgu(Q(v,f(k)), P(v,f(k))) = undefined
    foo("P(v,f(k))", "Q(v,f(k))");
   
    // mgu(Q(f(g(c)),c), Q(f(x),h(y))) = mgu(Q(f(x),h(y)), Q(f(g(c)),c)) = undefined
    foo("Q(f(g(c)),c)", "Q(f(x),h(y))");

    // mgu(R(x,g(u)), R(k,x)) = mgu(R(k,x), R(x,g(u))) = undefined
    foo("R(x,g(u))", "R(k,x)");

    // mgu(P(x,f(x)), P(h(y),y)) = mgu(P(h(y),y), P(x,f(x))) = undefined
    foo("P(x,f(x))", "P(h(y),y)");

    // mgu(R(f(a,x)), R(f(u))) = mgu(R(f(a,x)), R(f(u))) = undefined
    foo("R(f(a,x))", "R(f(u))");

where foo() is whatever you name the wrapper.
Though it seems that test 1 and 2 are the same.
Fix typo:
.DELTE_ON_ERROR:

should be:
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:

Moreover, the makefile lacks a lot of (useful) compiler flags (-Wpedantic, -Werror, et cetera). You also need not define your own rules; Make defines COMPILE.c and LINK.c. The -std=gnu11 is also not required; the code is not using anything GNU-specific, and the attributes would still be available when compiling with -std=c11. Clang and ICX also support GNU C's attributes, so you'd be better off trying to detect all three of them.


#include "atom.c"


Please don't do this - you should link against the object file, rather than re-compiling the source.


    @echo "\e[1;33m"Running Tests:"\e[39;49m"


Please don't embed control characters in output like that - it makes for very hard reading for users whose output device is different from yours.  If you want terminal-specific characters to be embedded, please use tput to generate them from portable descriptions.

Your help message defines CONSTANT, but never uses it.
Should be
        "\tTERM       ::=  FUNCTION TERM-LIST | VARIABLE | CONSTANT\n"

